# Ember JS how to get an array with unique property values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ember.js, unique

I have a array with objects which has different properties. There are objects with similar properties. For example,

```
var array=[{'property':1},{'property':2},{'property':1}]
```

How to get the array with unique properties using ember js?

Finally I need an array of

```
[{'property':1},{'property':2}]
```

your kind help is really appreciated.

**Update**: I tried the uniq() method. But that does not allow to pass the property as ember allows with sorting.

Thank You!

Comment: Did you tried anything, post it to see the point of issue?

Comment: have a look at lodash - I use that in both node and ember apps for this sort of thing

Answer (score 9):

We can do it in just one line of code using Ember's uniqBy method.

Suppose we have this array =>

```
var arrayName=[{'property':1},{'property':2},{'property':1}]
```

To get an unique array, you need to do the following =>

```
arrayName.uniqBy('property');
```

Which will return the following =>

```
var arrayName=[{'property':1},{'property':2}]
```

uniqBy returns a new enumerable that contains only items containing a unique property value. The default implementation returns an array regardless of the receiver type.([link to Ember Guide](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_uniqBy))

Comment: @user1438823 please mark the correct answer if you got your solution.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to use the [`filter` method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.NativeArray.html#method_filter) in conjunction with [`isAny` method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.NativeArray.html#method_isAny)

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

  unique: function(){
    var model = this.get('model');
    var uniqueObjects = [];

    return model.filter(function(item){
      if(!uniqueObjects.isAny('property', item.property)){
        uniqueObjects.push(item);

        return true;
      }

      return false;
    });
  }.property('model')
});
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nusopi/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: ArrayController will be deprecated in ember 1.11.

Comment: Sure. The main point of the example is the `unique` property whether it lives inside a controller or component. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution using `forEach` (& not forgetting to use `get` for `item.get('property')`):

```
unique: Em.computed('model', function() {
  var uniqueObjects = [];
  this.get('model').forEach(function(item) {
    if (!uniqueObjects.isAny('property', item.get('property'))) {
      uniqueObjects.addObject(item);
    }
  });
  return uniqueObjects;
})
```